# Self Signed SSL Certificates in IIS 6

Tags: security, iis, ssl, https, iis-6

I'm new to SSL in IIS 6.  I download and the IIS 6 Resource Kit and followed the instructions here:

http://www.somacon.com/p42.php

My IIS webpage is at: review.mprinc.com/webvts.

If I go to http://review.mprinc.com/webvts, the site is still there and if I go to https://review.mprinc.com/webvts, it appears the SSL is working.

Is that all I have to do? How do I forward the http: page to my https: one?

Answer (score 0):

If SSL is working then you should redirect http to https for all site or for certain pages and a short description on how could be done can be found here [How to Force Redirection From HTTP to HTTPS on IIS 6.0](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dorr/archive/2009/01/13/how-to-force-redirection-from-http-to-https-on-iis-6-0.aspx). Also it is recommended to [configure a default page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true).